# Setting Apache Tomcat JRE_HOME without setting environment variable

Tags: tomcat, environment-variables

I have a server which uses Java 6 for an Oracle implementation. But I want to install a Tomcat Apache Server on it but with Java 8. So in order to not mix the system environment here's what I want to do:

-Get Apache Tomcat and JRE/JDK as zip formats. Extract them on a folder and tell my Apache Tomcar to use that JRE/JDK.

AFAIK. I can edit the JAVA_HOME and JAVA_JRE in the catalina.bat file and I am now trying it on a laptop. I set my catalina.bat file but when I try to run the apache server through command prompt I get the message "Neither the JAVA_HOME or JRE_HOME environment variables are defined(...)"

This is my catalina.bat file after I edited it.

```
echo Using CATALINA_BASE:   "%CATALINA_BASE%"
echo Using CATALINA_HOME:   "%CATALINA_HOME%"
echo Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "%CATALINA_TMPDIR%"
if ""%1"" == ""debug"" goto use_jdk
echo Using JRE_HOME:        "D:\ANDRES\Descargas\apache-tomcat-8.5.43-windows-x64\jre1.8.0_221\"
goto java_dir_displayed
:use_jdk
echo Using JAVA_HOME:       "D:\ANDRES\Descargas\apache-tomcat-8.5.43-windows-x64\jdk1.8.0_221\"
:java_dir_displayed
echo Using CLASSPATH:       "%CLASSPATH%"
```

So my question overall is. Is there a way to set the Tomcat server to use JRE_HOME from another route that is not defined on the system environment variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to modify `catalina.bat`. You can do that by setting the variables in the `setenv` script of your Tomcat installation. You seem to be using Windows, so here is an example of a `setenv.bat` to change `JRE_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME`.

Create the file `%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\setenv.bat` with the following content:

```
set "JRE_HOME=D:\ANDRES\Descargas\apache-tomcat-8.5.43-windows-x64\jre1.8.0_221"
set "JAVA_HOME=D:\ANDRES\Descargas\apache-tomcat-8.5.43-windows-x64\jdk1.8.0_221"
exit /b 0
```

This way, only Tomcat will be affected by the change in variables, all other processes use `%PATH%` and system global variables as always.

`setenv` is described in the [Tomcat docs, chapter 3.2](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/RUNNING.txt)

Comment: Thanks! This worked like a charm!